# IIS returning 401.0 when accessing MVC app

Tags: iis-8, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC5 site that has been running in an IIS8 server for a couple months now. Suddenly, the server is returning 401.0 errors for some people. Not everyone, just some. And there's no real pattern that I can determine (however, I'm not very good with IIS, nor am I good at reading the logs).

Here is a successful call:

`2016-03-30 19:56:16 GET /web - internal\C15919 **.27.28.86 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - - **.27.28.86 200 0 0 3990 548 3843`

And here's one that fails:

`2016-03-30 19:48:26 GET /Web - INTERNAL\c58199 **.75.16.122 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.3) WT_FPC=;+__utma=252045595.1829868083.1414413591.1446131386.1450209330.7;+__utmz=252045595.1433439046.3.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided);+oo_inv_reprompt=1 - d-medman.**.com 401 0 0 5123 1037 31`

I've tried many things:

- Removed any `[Authorize]` tags from the controller within the application
- Changed Web.config to have ``
- Changing the app pool identity
- Changing anonymous authentication to the app pool ID
- Disabling anonymous authentication

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this? I'm really not sure what to do here.